# Handle python selenium webdriver Connection Refused error. (Chrome)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, try-catch, connection-refused

I can't understand how to catch exception of webdriver

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(
    "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en-GB")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format(proxy))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=chrome_options)

try:
     #here some things with webdriver
except Exception as e:
     #here I want to quit webriver if some exception will come
     driver.quit()
```

As I understand try-except block must handle all exceptions, but errors like

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=56963): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/61d7c70479adfb73b0c8d6aecf0cdb2e/element (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff90feeafd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 175, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

```
('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 710, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1369, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 310, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

killing script and chromium process still live in background.
[cmd after sript killed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNQDS.png)
Can you help me please how to catch this errors and continue script? Or how to quit webdriver if this errors come?

Thanks for answers!

In google I found much answers about user agent and work with webdriver after using quit(), but I don't do this and use user agent for it.

Comment: What are you doing inside try block?. Are you sure your code is failing inside try block?

Comment: Yes,I am sure. I see this in stacktrace. It can be crashed on opening website or even on  driver.find_element() call.

Comment: Can you try to keep your except line like: `except:`? Just that

Comment: @JakyRuby thanks for answer, but seems error still killing script even with just except:. Also how I can get error message (to log it) if I use just except without variable for error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the kind of exception you are getting is not under `Exception` type of exceptions. You can do this in order to get what you want.

You can try this:

```
# Needed libs
import sys

try:
    #here some things with webdriver, in my example is divide by 0
    1 / 0
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()
    print(f"Error: {e[0]}")
    print(f"Error: {e[1]}")
    print(f"Error: {e[2]}")
```